# Wrapping objects around a helmet

Tags: modifiers

Currently I'm trying to model this military-style FAST helmet. I'm running into difficulties with wrapping this velcro around the side as well as this mount on the front (both circled), I've tried shrinkwrap for the velcro, but it doesn't seem to want to work with planes around the surface, and I'm unsure on how to go about modeling this mount on the front and making it flush with the helmet. Am I doing something wrong with the modifiers? How would I go about doing this?

([image: military FAST helmet]

Comment: I think you would be better off intersecting the helmet with the mount, and then Boolean-ing it to union them.

Comment: Duplicate some of the geometry from the helmet and then P > Separate by selection and you can just move it out a bit and hit it with a solidify modifier.

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll give these things a shot.